# Using wp.data.select get actual tags (not id's) used in post

Tags: javascript, block-editor

I am trying to retrieve the tag's used by the current post in the editor.

Using the console from my browser;

```
wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'tags' )
```

this will return the used tag id's but **how do I retrieve the actual tags?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`getEntityRecord()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/data/data-core/#getEntityRecord) like so:

```js
const tag_ids = wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'tags' );

// the last parameter is always the tag ID (and just one single ID)
const tag = wp.data.select( 'core' ).getEntityRecord( 'taxonomy', 'post_tag', tag_ids[0] );

console.log( tag ? tag.name : 'still resolving or no such tag..' );
```

Or use [`getEntityRecords()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/data/data-core/#getEntityRecords) with the [`include` parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/tags/#arguments) set to the tag IDs:

```js
const tag_ids = wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'tags' );

// the last parameter is an object containing the REST API endpoint arguments
const tags = wp.data.select( 'core' ).getEntityRecords( 'taxonomy', 'post_tag', { include: tag_ids } );

console.log( tags && tags[0] ? tags[0].name : 'still resolving or tags[0] not available' );
```

Just remember that `getEntityRecord()` and `getEntityRecords()` perform an AJAX request to the `/wp/v2/tags` route in the REST API, so the functions may not immediately return the response from the API.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So to get a tag name from the browser console I type wp.data.select( 'core' ).getEntityRecord( 'taxonomy', 'post_tag', THE_ID_HERE ) and because it is an AJAX request I will have to do this twice. I can't seem to find a way to show the tags in the ' help: ' of an input field, but that is an other question. I will mark this as solved. Thanks!